# What is this pipe and can/should I tile over it?

Tags: basement, drain, pipe

[image]I ripped up the stick on tile in our basement bathroom so I can install ceramic tile and there is an access port with a mystery pipe in it. The bathroom has a tub, toilet and sink already so I'm guessing this is either for a floor drain or some sort of cleanout. The pipe is 5" in diameter and is located right next to the doorway.
Any ideas what this is and is it okay to tile over it? I suppose if it is for a floor drain then installing a drain here would be the reasonable thing to do, or would that put me at more risk of backup?

Any information would be appreciated.

photo below

Comment: Looks like a cleanout to me.

Comment: ... and it should not be tiled over in a permanent manner.

Comment: Remove that cap and start running some water and see what happens... it's probably a cleanout.

Comment: Presumably there is a plastic cover that fits over this?  If you don't like the way it looks you could get a brass or aluminum one that suits your bathroom, or you ought to be able to find a cover with a recess that accepts tile, so you'll only see a ring of metal or plastic.  You could make one out of wood with a rubber gasket.